How to fix time.process_time() not working when wrapped around a function run with Numba jit, with parallelisation=True
I have a function that has a numba @njit wrapper around it to make it faster, I've set parallel=True to make it run faster. And now want to measure the time it takes, using time.process_time(), however the time i get is way of.
start_time = time.process_time()
cubes_numba_dict = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.UniTuple(types.int32, 3),
    value_type=types.float64[:,:] # Should be matrix
)

cubes_numba_dict, x_grid, y_grid, z_grid = creating_dict(cubes_numba_dict, data_np, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, z_min, z_max, cube_width, sort_width_multiple)
create_dict_time = time.process_time()
print(f"It took: {create_dict_time-start_time} to create dictionary.")

When I time the process IRL using my phone, I get around 11 seconds, and the print statement says 90 seconds.
I have 6 threads on my CPU, is the time that time.process_time() just a multiple of number of threads? If not, how do I know the true processing time?

Have you tried using the timeit module instead of your own timing code?

time.process_time() measures the "CPU time" and not the wall-clock time. What you want is apparently the later so the function is not the suited one. What about time.perf_counter()
